# Javascript array, with array inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to store an array of information, with a subset of information for each one. so I want something like:

```
var users = [{userID:1, userName:robert}, {userID:2, userName:daniel}]
```

then to retrieve the variable:

```
users.userID // 1, 2
users.userName // robert, daniel
```

or something, i want to be able to get the information associated with the userID.

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is; you need to access a specific element, `users[n]`. Are you asking how to get *all* the ids and names?

Comment: do you expect `users.userID` and `users.userName` to get you more than one thing?

Comment: users.userID returns undefined.

Comment: @DylanCross `users[0].userID` and `users[1].userID`

Comment: you need to use users[n].userID

Comment: @DylanCross also make sure that you put robert and daniel in quotes

Comment: That doesn't work though either.

Comment: @DylanCross Its probably because you need to do "robert" and "daniel" whereas you have robert and daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your problem I would think about redoing the array along the line of the following

```
var users = { 'id1' : { 'userName' :'robert'},
              'id2': { 'userName ': 'daniel'}};

alert(users.id1.userName);
alert( eval('users.id' + 1 + '.userName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
var desiredUserID = 2;

var userList = [ {userID: 1, userName: "robert"}, {userID:2, userName:"daniel"} ];

for(x=0;x<=userList.length;x++) {

    if(userList[x].userID == desiredUserID){

         alert(userList[x].userName);   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this generates an array of user IDs:

```
 [{userID:1, userName:robert},
        {userID:2, userName:daniel}].map(function (x) { return x.userID; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, in a variety of ways. Suppose you have:

```
var users = [{userID: 1, userName: robert}, {userID: 2, userName: daniel}];
```

To retrieve the `userID` and `userName` for Robert, you have access them via `users[0].userID` and `users[0].userName`.

If instead you want to retrieve them by `users.userID[0]` and `users.userName[0]`, then you need to store it this way:

```
var users = {userID: [1, 2], userName: [robert, daniel]};
```

If you are asking how to transform the first form to the second, use this:

```
function transform(source) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        for (property in source[i]) {
            if (typeof result[property] == "undefined")
                result[property] = [];
            result[property].push(source[i][property]);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var transformed_users = transform(users);
```

Do note that this transform function is specific to your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
        var array1 = new Array(1,2,3,4);
        var array2 = new Array(8,9,10,11,12,13);
        var array3 = new Array( array1, array2);
        console.log(array1);
        console.log(array2);
        console.log(array3);
```

Will give you the right results